# Kubernetes Kubelet doesn't have access to Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubelet

I have a 5-nodes Kubernetes cluster of which 1 is the master (set up with kubeadm). When I first deployed the master node I deployed also the kubernetes dashboard so it's running on the same machine. After that I joined the other nodes to the cluster.

Now when I deploy a pod using a YAML file it stays in the `ContainerCreating` state. So I describe the pod and saw the machine where it was deployed. I SSH'd in the machine and checked first `docker ps -a` I could determine that the image was not started nor even was it pulled. So I looked into the kubelet logs (I didn't copy everything but this will give a pretty good idea):

```
E0131 11:05:40.486422    2873 server.go:459] Kubelet needs to run as uid `0`. It is being run as 1000
W0131 11:05:40.486616    2873 server.go:469] write /proc/self/oom_score_adj: permission denied
W0131 11:05:40.486978    2873 server.go:669] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
W0131 11:05:40.491423    2873 kubelet_network.go:69] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
I0131 11:05:40.491498    2873 kubelet.go:477] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
W0131 11:05:40.495353    2873 plugins.go:210] can't set sysctl net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables: open /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables: permission denied
I0131 11:05:40.503259    2873 docker_manager.go:257] Setting dockerRoot to /var/lib/docker
I0131 11:05:40.503308    2873 docker_manager.go:260] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
I0131 11:05:40.506028    2873 server.go:770] Started kubelet v1.5.2
E0131 11:05:40.506209    2873 server.go:481] Starting health server failed: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: bind: address already in use
E0131 11:05:40.506300    2873 kubelet.go:1145] Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /
I0131 11:05:40.506413    2873 server.go:123] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
W0131 11:05:40.506445    2873 kubelet.go:1224] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
E0131 11:05:40.507209    2873 kubelet.go:1228] error creating pods directory: mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods: permission denied
I0131 11:05:40.509613    2873 status_manager.go:125] Kubernetes client is nil, not starting status manager.
I0131 11:05:40.509656    2873 kubelet.go:1714] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
I0131 11:05:40.509710    2873 kubelet.go:1725] skipping pod synchronization - [error creating pods directory: mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods: permission denied container runtime is down]
F0131 11:05:40.509522    2873 server.go:148] listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10255: bind: address already in use
```

There are a lot of permission issues. I have no idea how to fix this. I've added root and the user account to the docker group to see if it fixes it, but it doesn't.

## Update

Above I did a `kubelet logs` and that is why you get the uid message. When I execute `sudo kubelet logs` I get these results:

```
I0201 15:36:01.386564    5082 feature_gate.go:181] feature gates: map[]
W0201 15:36:01.386861    5082 server.go:400] No API client: no api servers specified
I0201 15:36:01.386953    5082 docker.go:356] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I0201 15:36:01.386991    5082 docker.go:376] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
I0201 15:36:01.401737    5082 manager.go:143] cAdvisor running in container: "/user.slice"
W0201 15:36:01.415664    5082 manager.go:151] unable to connect to Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp [::1]:15441: getsockopt: connection refused
I0201 15:36:01.431725    5082 fs.go:117] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/mmcblk0p2:{mountpoint:/var/lib/docker/aufs major:179 minor:2 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0}]
I0201 15:36:01.440439    5082 manager.go:198] Machine: {NumCores:4 CpuFrequency:1920000 MemoryCapacity:3519315968 MachineID:a9807123b38d1f069a44f0b7588b5884 SystemUUID:03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009 BootID:7e71fe9b-a9d8-4921-80c7-9d09e49ed1ef Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/mmcblk0p2 Capacity:57295605760 Type:vfs Inodes:3563520 HasInodes:true}] DiskMap:map[179:0:{Name:mmcblk0 Major:179 Minor:0 Size:62545461248 Scheduler:deadline} 179:8:{Name:mmcblk0boot0 Major:179 Minor:8 Size:4194304 Scheduler:deadline} 179:16:{Name:mmcblk0boot1 Major:179 Minor:16 Size:4194304 Scheduler:deadline} 179:24:{Name:mmcblk0rpmb Major:179 Minor:24 Size:4194304 Scheduler:deadline}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:datapath MacAddress:72:36:99:b2:ba:be Speed:0 Mtu:1410} {Name:dummy0 MacAddress:ea:c7:5e:6d:29:75 Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:enp1s0 MacAddress:00:07:32:3e:17:8c Speed:1000 Mtu:1500} {Name:vxlan-6784 MacAddress:5a:81:bb:f6:00:d7 Speed:0 Mtu:1500} {Name:weave MacAddress:92:64:f5:c5:57:a7 Speed:0 Mtu:1410}] Topology:[{Id:0 Memory:3519315968 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0] Caches:[{Size:24576 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1] Caches:[{Size:24576 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]} {Id:2 Threads:[2] Caches:[{Size:24576 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]} {Id:3 Threads:[3] Caches:[{Size:24576 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1}]}] Caches:[]}] CloudProvider:Unknown InstanceType:Unknown InstanceID:None}
I0201 15:36:01.442170    5082 manager.go:204] Version: {KernelVersion:4.4.0-31-generic ContainerOsVersion:Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS DockerVersion:1.12.3 CadvisorVersion: CadvisorRevision:}
I0201 15:36:01.444559    5082 cadvisor_linux.go:152] Failed to register cAdvisor on port 4194, retrying. Error: listen tcp :4194: bind: address already in use
W0201 15:36:01.449146    5082 container_manager_linux.go:205] Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! This will be a fatal error by default starting in K8s v1.6! In the meantime, you can opt-in to making this a fatal error by enabling --experimental-fail-swap-on.
W0201 15:36:01.449653    5082 server.go:669] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
W0201 15:36:01.457574    5082 kubelet_network.go:69] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
I0201 15:36:01.457658    5082 kubelet.go:477] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
I0201 15:36:01.471512    5082 docker_manager.go:257] Setting dockerRoot to /var/lib/docker
I0201 15:36:01.471570    5082 docker_manager.go:260] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
I0201 15:36:01.474678    5082 server.go:770] Started kubelet v1.5.2
E0201 15:36:01.474926    5082 server.go:481] Starting health server failed: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: bind: address already in use
E0201 15:36:01.475062    5082 kubelet.go:1145] Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /
W0201 15:36:01.475208    5082 kubelet.go:1224] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
I0201 15:36:01.475702    5082 kubelet_node_status.go:204] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
I0201 15:36:01.479587    5082 server.go:123] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
F0201 15:36:01.481605    5082 server.go:148] listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10255: bind: address already in use
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run kubelet as root (see first line of log). This a a known limitation at the moment:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869

Comment: It is running as root. When I do `sudo ps -aux | grep kubelet` I can see that it's running as root. However I did not add sudo to the `kubelet log` command in t he question. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

The `kubelet` tool doesn't have a `logs` subcommand, so when you ran `kubelet logs`, you're actually starting the kubelet process again without any valid args. The lack of valid args is where most of those messages are coming from, and it ultimately stops running with the message `bind: address already in use`, because something, presumably your existing kubelet process (the one which was run as `root`) is already bound to that port.

How you view the kubelet's logs depends on how you setup your kubelet processes, I.E. for my setup ([kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)) you can `journalctl -u kubelet`, for others you might look for a `/var/log/<kubelet-log-file>.log`, or similar.